# Оправдано ли применение Рекурсии в данном коде?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, понимаю что вопрос элементарный для большинства - являюсь новичком, буду благодарен за обоснованные ответы. Есть данный код, как более правильно (**со стороны оптимизации потребления памяти**) будет делать возврат в меню выбора доступных функций программы которое находится в методе void SwitchMessage (), после выполнения.

Насколько я понимаю есть 3 варианта:

1. Рекурсия внутри SwitchMessage ();
2. goto;
3. Способ который сейчас реализован в коде.

.

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
class Program
{
    Book book = new Book();
    void Main()
    {
        Programin(1);
    }

    void WellcomeMessage ()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("Личная Библиотека");
    }

    void SwitchMessage ()
    {
        int inputSwitchDone;
        Block1:
        Console.WriteLine("Для просмотра существующих Книг - введите 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Для добавления новой книги - введите 2");
        string inputSwitch = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(inputSwitch, out inputSwitchDone))
        {
            //SwitchMessage ();
            //goto Block1;
            book.Switcher(inputSwitchDone);
            Programin(2);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    void Programin(int switch1)
    {
        switch (switch1)
        {
            case 1:
                WellcomeMessage();
                SwitchMessage();
                break;
            case 2:
                SwitchMessage();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void ErrorMessage ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введен Неверный тип данных, повторите ввод");
        SwitchMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мне так вы лишнего написали кода. Поглядите мой пример. Там не надо ни рекурсий, ни goto - просто цикл ввода юзера:

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        WellcomeMessage();
        while (SwitchMessage()) ;
    }

    void WellcomeMessage()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("Личная Библиотека");
    }

    bool SwitchMessage()
    {
        int inputSwitchDone;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Для просмотра существующих Книг - введите 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Для добавления новой книги - введите 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Для выхода - введите 3");
        string inputSwitch = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(inputSwitch, out inputSwitchDone))
        {
            switch (inputSwitchDone)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Просмотр книг");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Добавление книг");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Выход");
                    return false;
                default:
                    ErrorMessage();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage();
        }

        return true;
    }

    void ErrorMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введен Неверный тип данных, повторите ввод");            
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересный подход с while в Main() , и bool SwitchMessage(). Спасибо, за ответ !